# Get an array of DOM-Elements in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get an array of DOM-Elements in Vue.js. If I had the following HTML structure:

```
 <select onchange="toggleDisability(this);" class="mySelect" id="mySelect1"> 
 </select>
 <select onchange="toggleDisability(this);" class="mySelect" id="mySelect2">
 </select>
```

I could get all elements with the `mySelect` class with normal JS like:

```
var arraySelects = document.getElementsByClassName('mySelect');
```

Now I am trying to get the same thing with Vue `$refs`, but I am always getting the last element. it looks like:

```
<select id="selection-x" ref="Axis"  @change="log($event)"></select>
<select id="selection-y" ref="Axis"  @change="log($event)"></select>
```

and

```
        log(selectElement){
   var arraySelects = this.$refs['Axis'];
}
```

Of course there are also options ,so that `@change` event gets emitted, but it doesn't do what I want it to. I want to get an array of the elements with the same `ref` just like it works in the example above for normal JS, where you are getting an array of  `select` elements whose `class` attribute equals to `mySelect`.

P.S. I know `ref` should be unique, but how could it be then used for this particular usecase?

Comment: *"... it doesn't do what I want it to."* What do you want it to do?

Comment: Check my edited version please

Comment: it's no way, but you can custom a directive like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multi-ref

Comment: best practice is to specify a `ref` for the parent element. `this.$refs.selectwrap.children`

Comment: Thank you Joaner your second answer is exactly what I need

Answer (score 3):

No. It is not possible with `ref` and `$refs`. If you wish to do DOM manipulation then,  use `vue-directive` or directly access DOM from the root element of the component like:

```
Vue.extend({
    mounted() {
        // Do what you want with your children.
        const children = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.mySelect');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to do this was to set a ref on the parent element (thanks joaner in original comment), but then I also needed to run my code in the "updated" hook so my data was loaded before trying to access the dom (I also have a v-if on the same element I want to reference children):

template:

```
<ul v-if="dataLoaded" ref="eventlist">
    <li class="eventItem"></li>
    <li class="eventItem"></li>
    <li class="eventItem"></li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
updated() {
  let eventItems = this.$refs.eventlist.children
  console.log(eventItems)
}
```