# How to select multiple dom elements with same class in vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I Have multiple dom elements with same classname , i want to select all elements and using forEach function i want to add click event listener to it.

In vanilla javascript we select all elements using querySelectorAll

```
classname.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //logic
  }
})
```

how to do same as above using vue js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021808/5252522

Comment: You can use a query selector to get all the elements with the class name, and then this forloop that you have should work fine

Comment: You should probably use template refs rather than a query selector tho.